# Scroll unable to move in bootstrap onchange of dropdown - dynamically loading content to div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a bootstrap html page with container div as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="container">
     <!--Contents-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS styling as follows:

```
html body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

html body .container-fluid.body-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

I have a drop down box and in initially in `onchange` the content loads in the div and the `overflow-y :auto` works fine. I again changed the dropdown so that the div will replace with new set of elements. **In this case Scroll not working**. I have inspected and the styles remains same there are no changes.
Scroll showing as shown in figure:

[image]

Why Scroll is not working in second time? Please suggest me what change should I make to fix it.

Comment: have you tried navigating to the bottom of the page with keyboard? If yes then the problem is that there is something tha overlaps with the scrollbars. In any case make a fiddle or plunker with your dummy html to help us understand your problem

Comment: @JmRag yes buddy the keyboard also not working. What I am doing is I am creating a table using jquery and adding inside a div in my dropdown onchange. In first it will load on onload and in every onchange it will be replaced with new content. I hope you understand the working. The problem is in second time Scroll it not working. It is tedious task to create a fiddle because it contains more